# My 404 page in wordpress not show

Tags: wordpress

my 404 page in my site in Wordpress not show when user type a incorrect address and show a page with widget and other thing.
i use a custom permalink %postname% before this change 404 work correctly but after change my permalink not work.
can any one help me wordpress doc cant help me.
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

I change my permalink  to `%postname%.html` and 404 page work correct